# Android get list of string resources from special file

Tags: android, android-resources

For example, i have **my_string.xml** file with strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="my_string">My string</string>
    <string name="another_string">Another string</string>
    {...}
</resources>
```

Is it possible to get this strings to list/hashmap programmatically? Yeh, i know that i can take it [by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637515/getting-string-resource-by-name) or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690642/1991579). But i need to get it dynamically programmatically, for example, to `HashMap<String, String>`

Or all string resources will merge together after building and it's not possible to separate it?

Comment: Why you need this ? Because you have arrays.xml who you can put directly array of strings. <string-array name="myarray"><item>A</item></string-array>

Comment: @jaumard oh, it's hard to tell =/

Comment: Ok ^^ you can't have strings from one file cause there are merge together at compilation :/ but you can make an array yourself like i tell you  <string-array name="myarray"><item>@string/string1_from_file</item></string-array> but you have to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access all the Strings from the `strings.xml` file you could use reflection on the `R.string` class.

```
Field[] fields = R.strings.class.getFields();
String[] allStringsNames = new String[fields.length];
for (int  i =0; i < fields.length; i++) {           
    allStringsNames[i] = fields[i].getName();
}
```

You can then store them in `Hashmap` or wherever you want

Comment: I don't need ALL strings, i want to take strings only from one file, That's the problem =/

Answer (score 1):

Put the file in the `raw` folder. Then you have to open the file

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);
```

and parse the content manually, for instance save the list as xml or json and parse it and build your desired HashMap or whatever you like. Keep in mind that this may be a blocking operation and should not run on the main UI thread, run it async, but it depends on the length of the file you try to parse, but in general you should run that in an async thread

---- Update
You could do something like this:

```
int stringRes[] = {R.string.my_string, R.string.another_string}
List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int id : stringRes){

   String str = getResources().getString(id);
   // TODO do some if check if you want to keep that string or whatever you want to ...
   myStrings.add(str);
}
```

you could store them into a HashMap(but getResources().getString() acts already like a HashMap ) or List

Comment: In this way i can't take string via getResources().getStrings(), but i need it to.

Comment: ok, so what is your problem? You know `R.string.my_string` right? So you can access the String with `getResources().getStrings(R.string.my_string)` right? I have updated my answer, but I'm not sure what you want to do ...

Comment: i need full list of strings, and sometimes i need to get string by key)

Comment: what is "the key" ...  what's the problem to provide a list with all possible strings like `int stringRes[] = {R.string.my_string, R.string.another_string}` and do a for loop where you check if you want to load the the string or not ... I can't help you if you don't provide more details about the problem description

Comment: Designer gave me this file, so with some basic string i work like R.string.another_string, but also i want to take string as HashMap. And it's not good to change code for new strings. Mb i should use StringArray =/

Comment: StringArray should work, however you have to know the key anyway ... so I can't still see the reason why somehting like this would not work `int stringRes[] = {R.string.my_string, R.string.another_string}`? I mean, also in the StringArray you want to have a hashmap? and therefore you have to know the key for every single entry, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the XML file is to act as a "hashmap" kind of... you can always get a string by using `context` and the `R.string` reference. I'm assuming you are aware of this, so then you must be trying to create a simplified reference to this?

Creating a `HashMap` requires either static references (which are not available for XML) or a runtime creation of the list. You can create the list in the `Application` class, but I would caution against that. You may have trouble referencing the `context` but again, you can use the `Application` constructor to make sure you have a reference to context.

Beyond that, you should check into the `StringArray` resource. It does not allow you to reference a string using another string because it is an array. Here are the docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

If it's super-important to use a `HashMap` then you should probably not use XML and should just create a `static` class. The XML resource files are primarily used for centralized data (to ease modifications to static strings) and, more so, multi-lingual purposes. Static `HashMap`s are not the proper use-case.

Comment: I can't create static class. Cause designer gives me this string file, and he shouldn't work with code.

Comment: If you have those constraints, then you can create the string array and then assign each index a string value to create your HashMap... maybe use SmilerParser as an example too.