# how to get color code from color tag in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there any way to get color code
**For example**

```
   <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#ff000000</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff000000</color>
        <color name="colorAccent">#ff008dcd</color>
        <color name="colorControlHighlight">#ff757575</color>
        <color name="colorControlNormal">#ff57beee</color>
        </resources>
```

So I want to get the color name and color code

Let's take the first code
So it's **colorPrimary** and code is **#ff000000**

*Attention*
This code is not a color.xml but it's a string and I want to take the name and color code from it

Comment: Give an example of what you want. Not like the xml which is misleading.

Comment: Ok so let's say there as a Button and two textviews and the first textview or textview1 contains the code which is just above and what I want is when the button clicked it should take the color code and show it in textview2

Comment: Edit your question and post there your example with real values and the expected result.

Comment: First i would like to tell you if there is any mistake in my English so sorry for that because I don't speak English very much and ok I'm trying to give you an example

Comment: Ok let's say ( <color name="colorPrimary">#ff000000</color> ) this code have a name which is colorPrimary and code which is #ff000000 so is it possible to take the list of all codes like this one

Answer (score 0):

Without alpha you can do this:

```
int colorPrimary = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
String strColorPrimary = "#"+Integer.toHexString(colorPrimary);
```

Comment: No you didn't understand it's not a color xml but a string and I want to show color code and name in another string

Comment: If I could then why I asked the question

Comment: Sorry but I don't speak English very much

Answer (score 0):

Similar question answered here: 
[Android get list of string resources from special file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635641/android-get-list-of-string-resources-from-special-file)

So you can try to enumerate color resources in your case to find name that matches specific value.